# invoke external webservice in openesb

Tags: web-services, soap, bpel, open-esb

I have created a simple webserivce locally.
Imported its wsdl in the bpel project and tried to invoke it.
I tested the webservice directly from the browser and it works fine.
However running the test case in the CA gives me the following error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
  <faultstring>BPCOR-6135: A fault was not handled in the process scope; Fault Name is {http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling}systemFault; Fault Data is &amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:message xmlns:sxeh=&amp;quot;http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;sxeh:faultMessage&amp;quot; version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; xmlns:jbi=&amp;quot;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jbi/wsdl-11-wrapper&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:part&amp;gt;The server sent HTTP status code 500: Unable to connect&amp;lt;/jbi:part&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/jbi:message&amp;gt;. Sending errors for the pending requests in the process scope before terminating the process instance</faultstring>
  <faultactor>sun-bpel-engine</faultactor>
  <detail>
    <detailText>BPCOR-6135: A fault was not handled in the process scope; Fault Name is {http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling}systemFault; Fault Data is &amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:message xmlns:sxeh=&amp;quot;http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;sxeh:faultMessage&amp;quot; version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; xmlns:jbi=&amp;quot;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jbi/wsdl-11-wrapper&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:part&amp;gt;The server sent HTTP status code 500: Unable to connect&amp;lt;/jbi:part&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/jbi:message&amp;gt;. Sending errors for the pending requests in the process scope before terminating the process instance
Caused by: BPCOR-6131: An Error status was received while doing an invoke (partnerLink=PartnerLink2, portType={http://testWs/}TestWebService, operation=hello)
BPCOR-6129: Line Number is 44
BPCOR-6130: Activity Name is Invoke1
Caused by: The server sent HTTP status code 500: Unable to connect</detailText>
  </detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you precise the version and the edition you are using.
Could you first use a tools such as SOAP UI to see if your WSDL (concrete part: port, IP) is ok.
Then if the wsdl is ok, What you try to do must work. 
Did you have a look on OpenESB documentation ?
www.open-esb.net You must be logged to access to the documentation.

If you don't success try to contact the community on contact@open-esb.net

regards

Paul